# Session level data in temporary tables and TVFs

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working with a catalogue system at present with many user settings and preferences. As such when we setup a session we create a list of allowed products.  These are currently stored in a table named like "allowedProducts_0001" where 0001 is the session ID.

We handle the data this way because there is a lot of complexity around product visibility that we do not wish to repeatedly process.

I have been asked to produce a TVF to select from this table, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM allowedProducts('0001')
```

The problem I have is that I cannot query from a dynamic table name, even though the output would be in a static format.

I have considered creating a single table with a column for session id, hence removing the need for dynamic sql, but the table would be too large to be efficient (100k+ products per session for some clients with many open sessions at once).

I cannot use temp tables because the calling system doesn't keep the sql connection open constantly (several hundred possible sessions at once).

IWe're currently supporting back as far as MSSQL2008-R2, but have the option of upgrading to newer servers as part of an upgrade program.

I'm looking for suggestions of how to work around these conditions.  Anybody have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't accomplish your goal with your current schema design. Unless you want to redesign your system, you are at a dead end; a TVF is simply not possible. You've been asked to do something that is impossible given the constraints of the system. Rather than focus on "how", focus on "what".

Comment: That was pretty much what I thought. I'm trying to get supporting evidence to go back with and say this isn't an option.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [partitioned tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/partitioned-tables-and-indexes).